# htacess redirect from php page to a different website?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This seems so trivial but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to redirect

```
http://website.com/something/file.php?var=1
```

to

```
http://website2.com/something/$1/
```

I've tried a bunch of things the latest was

```
Redirect 301 ^file.php\?var=([0-9]+)$ http://website2.com/something/$1/
```

I've even tried doing

```
Redirect 301 ^something/$ http://website2.com/something/1/
```

but that didn't work either. The only thing that I've gotten to work is a redirect on the whole site doing

```
Redirect 301 /$ http://website2.com/something/1/
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've done a lot of redirects in my day but this one is throwing me for a loop. I've even used htaccess checker that said my url matches my string but it didn't actually do anything.

Comment: _“Is there something I'm missing?”_ – the fact that `Redirect` only does prefix matching, but does _not_ use regular expressions maybe …? For the latter, there’s `RedirectMatch`.

Comment: I don't think RdirectMatch will work either since I need to do something based on the query string it seems like I will have to use a RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /something/file\.php\?var=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ something/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^something/(\d+)/?$ something/file.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```